# Convert Windows Char Set to Cyrillic

Tags: ms-access, character-encoding, vba, cyrillic

I have a set of tables from a client that are supposed to be Cyrillic, but I guess the original coding was wrong or not set.  All the text is gibberish.
If I past the text into an html page and set the encoding to Cyrillic-1251, I see the text as it should be.

```
Before: Ñèíèöûí À.Â.
After: Синицын А.В.
```

I've been looking for a VBA solution to convert the text in the tables without success. I thought this would be quick & easy, but so far no luck.

I'm running Win 7 with Access 2010

If you don't know Access, but have any VBA function to do this, I can adapt it to my needs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to solve the problem would be to export the table to CSV as code page 1252 ("ANSI") and then import it as code page 1251. I just tried that and for an existing table named [OldTable]

[image: OldTable.png]

the following VBA code

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DiskBounce()
    Const tempFilePath = "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.csv"
    DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acExportDelim, _
            TableName:="OldTable", _
            FileName:=tempFilePath, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            CodePage:=1252
    DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
            TableName:="NewTable", _
            FileName:=tempFilePath, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            CodePage:=1251
    Kill tempFilePath
End Sub
```

produced the following [NewTable]

[image: NewTable.png]

Comment: Was hoping for something more direct, and may still use this. In the meantime, +1 for 1 solution. If I end up using it, I'll come back and mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: OK, after playing around and doing more research, it appears that I can just add 836 to the double byte (if it's value is over 127). That would be handy for single strings, but it looks like your procedure is the easiest for whole tables. Thanks.